# Minimum distance between a point and a curve with optimiser failing for some points

Tags: python, numpy, mathematical-optimization, normals, scipy-optimize

I have a dataset with latitudes and longitudes to which I applied a 4th order linear regression and then proceeded to get the minimum distance (i.e., the [normal vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry))) to each datapoint to the regression using the `fmin_cobyla` function from `scipy.optimize`, as I had found in this [guide](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/02/14/Find-the-minimum-distance-from-a-point-to-a-curve/).

The `cobyla` optimiser takes the objective (i.e., the distance between two points), an initial guess and a constraint (i.e., the solution must be part of the regression curve). The code is as below:

```
def f(x):
    # Defines the regression equation
    return -1.28508857e-03 * x**4 + 7.06985581e-01 * x**3\
           -1.45729975e+02 * x**2 + 1.33400956e+04 * x - 4.57556176e+05

def obj(X):
    # Defines the distance between two points
    # X is an array containing latitude and longitude
    # long_t and lat_t are global variables
    x, y = X
    return np.sqrt((x - long_t)**2 + (y - lat_t)**2)

def c1(X):
    # Creates the constraint so that a solution must be part of the regression curve
    x, y = X
    return f(x) - y

K = fmin_cobyla(obj, x0=[127.5, 33], cons=[c1])
```

If, for instance, `long_t = 141.2393842` and `lat_t = 45.1779571`, we could plot the dataset, the regression line and the segment between this point and the curve as below:

[image: COBYLA finding a solution]

However, as I tested with some other datapoints, the optimiser couldn't find the solution and gave the datapoint itself as the solution. Below is an example with `long_t = 130.4183692` and `lat_t = 31.5231443`, whose optimisation `K` outputs `[130.41821497  31.52316012]` (essentially the same point):

[image: COBYLA entering panic mode]

As I have found out, this issue occurs with all datapoints that are **below** the regression curve, after applying the optimisation for the entire dataset:

[image: Finding patterns for this issue]

At first, I thought it could have to do with the initial guess `x0` being a set point above the curve and thus making it find a local minimum on these cases, but changing these parameters have not yielded success, neither by setting it below the curve, the datapoint itself, a point close to the datapoint or a point on the curve at the same longitude.

Why is that the COBYLA optimiser works for those datapoints above the curve, but not below? Should I be using this optimiser for the problem I am trying to solve? If not, which optimiser would you recommend and how to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment on the COBYLA optimizer behavior. However, you can simplify things by noting that your problem can be formulated as an *unconstrained* problem with respect to the `x` variable, since `y` can be replaced by `f(x)`. You may then call  `minimize_scalar` to give you the optimum value.

So let's define a new (scalar) objective function as

```
def obj2(x):
    y = f(x)
    return np.sqrt((x - long_t)**2 + (y - lat_t)**2)
```

and find the optimal `x` for the two cases you considered in your post. Note that `minimize_scalar` does not require an initial guess.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar

# first (good) case
long_t = 141.2393842
lat_t = 45.1779571
sol1 = minimize_scalar(obj2)
print(sol1.x, f(sol1.x), c1([sol1.x, f(sol1.x)]))

# second (bad) case
long_t = 130.4183692
lat_t = 31.5231443
sol2 = minimize_scalar(obj2)
print(sol2.x, f(sol2.x), c1([sol2.x, f(sol2.x)]))
```

> ```
> 143.4644668848802 43.30848453915678 0.0
> 129.46933497340797 32.164809729438275 0.0
> ```

Comment: Thanks! `minimize_scalar` did the job and no datapoints had issues anymore.